# What query to issue to extract only column names(no values)?

Tags: cassandra, hector

`RangeSliceQuery` has a convenient method to extract only the keys - `setReturnKeysOnly()` but I couldn't find something similar in `SliceQuery` (like `setReturnColumnNamesOnly()`).

Is this functionality provided somewhere in Hector API?

Answer (score 1):

If you want get only column names belonging to a particular column family, i can show you a way how you can achieve it using cql

```
select * from system.schema_columns WHERE keyspace_name='#KS' AND columnfamily_name='#CF' allow filtering;
```

Now i don't think it will be great technical hurdle to achieve the same thing using your hector api.

Cheers